# Button Press Event

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jfilechooser

I made a simple file menu. Upon clicking on file, you get a submenu named "New". When clicking on that brings up a dialog box. On the dialog box is a User input text field and a button. I am stummped on how to make an event where when you click on the button, the filechooser comes up.

Here is my code:

--NewFileBox.java--

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class NewFileBox implements ActionListener{

JTextField projectName = new JTextField();
JButton saveFile = new JButton();

public NewFileBox(){
    saveFile.addActionListener(this);
}

final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[]{
        new JLabel("Project Name"),
        projectName,
        new JButton("Save")
};

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E){
    if(E.getSource() == saveFile){
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    }
}
}
```

--Window.java--

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Window implements ActionListener{

//Create SubMenus
private JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("New...");
private JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("Open");
private JMenuItem item3 = new JMenuItem("Exit");

//Import Class
public NewFileBox nfb = new NewFileBox();

public Window(int w, int h, String title){
    JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

    //Menu Options
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");

    //Add ActionListener to SubMenu
    item1.addActionListener(this);
    item2.addActionListener(this);
    item3.addActionListener(this);


    menubar.add(menu);
    f.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    //Add SubMenus to File
    menu.add(item1);
    menu.add(item2);
    menu.add(item3);

    f.setSize(w, h);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E){
    //FILE
    if(E.getSource() == item1){     //New
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, nfb.inputs);
    }
    if(E.getSource() == item2){     //Open
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser("Open A File");
        fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    }
    if(E.getSource() == item3){     //Exit
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

--Game.java--

```
public class Game {

public static void main(String args[]){
    new Window(640, 480, "Autumn Engine");
}
}
```

Also, it would be great to know how to create that new file where the user saved it at when he/she presses the create button (I will make that button later) and when the user types in their project name; have the name added to the file name in FileChooser.

I know it is very much info. If you have any questions, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You never add your JButton to any component. You also have two JButtons present, one given an ActionListener and one not. Which one is to be used? Also your code can't compile -- please only post real compilable code so as not to confuse your issue for us.

Comment: I re-edited it. I hope that helps.

Comment: You create an instance of `saveFile`, `JButton saveFile = new JButton();`, when the class is initialised, however, you create ANOTHER instance in the `inputs` array...you attach a `ActionListener` to `saveFile`, but `saveFile` is NEVER added to any displayed UI component, so it can NEVER receive input from the user.  The button that is on the screen has no `ActionListener` registered to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, you've got two JButtons, one you've added the ActionListener to but do nothing with, and the other, the one you're trying to use, you don't add an ActionListener to. Solution: get rid of the 2nd button.

```
JButton saveFile = new JButton("Save"); // Put text into the button!

public NewFileBox(){
    saveFile.addActionListener(this);
}

final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[]{
        new JLabel("Project Name"),
        projectName,
        // new JButton("Save")  // Get rid of this!
        saveFile  // add this!
};
```